# First order stochastic dominance and summation of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ first-order stochastically dominates $Y$.

Moreover, $W_i$ is I.I.D. and follows Bernoulli distribution with success probability of $\alpha$

Then, does $X +\sum_{i=1}^{f(X)} W_i$ first-order stochastically dominate $Y +\sum_{i=1}^{f(Y)} W_i$?

Comment: What properties does the function $f$ have?  increasing/decreasing? Are the $\{W_i\}$ variables independent of $X$ and/or $Y$?

Comment: @Michael oh thanks for pointing out this.  $f'(x)>0$ holds.

Comment: @Michael  And yes, $W_i$ are independent of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

#### Claim:

Suppose that

- We have random variables $X, Y, \{W_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.
- $W_i\geq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.
- $(X,Y)$ is independent of $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.
- $P[X>x] \geq P[Y>x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
- $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ is a nondecreasing function.

Then $P[X + \sum_{i=1}^{f(X)} W_i > x] \geq P[Y + \sum_{i=1}^{f(Y)} W_i > x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

#### Proof:

Extend the probability space to include a random variable $U$ that is uniform over $(0,1)$ and is independent of $(X, Y, \{W_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty})$. Define random variables $A$ and $B$ (based entirely on $U$) by:

\begin{align}
A &= \inf \{x \in \mathbb{R} : P[X\leq x]\geq U\}\\
B &= \inf \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : P[Y\leq x]\geq U\}
\end{align} 
By standard theory for generating random variables according to a given distribution, we know that $A$ has the same distribution as $X$, and $B$ has the same distribution as $Y$.  Further, since $A$ and $B$ are based entirely on $U$, they are both independent of $(X,Y, \{W_i\})$. Finally, we see that $A\geq B$ always (since $P[X\leq x]\leq P[Y\leq x]$ for all $x$). So we have: 
\begin{align}
A &\geq B \\
f(A) &\geq f(B)\\
\sum_{i=1}^{f(A)} W_i &\geq \sum_{i=1}^{f(B)} W_i
\end{align}
Thus 
$$ A + \sum_{i=1}^{f(A)} W_i \geq B + \sum_{i=1}^{f(B)} W_i$$
But the left-hand-side has the same distribution as $X + \sum_{i=1}^{f(X)}W_i$ while the right-hand-side has the same distribution as $Y+\sum_{i=1}^{f(Y)}W_i$. 
$\Box$

Comment: Thanks! I have one question. Random variable $A$ is generated based on the distribution of $X$. How come $A$ is independent of $(X,Y,{W_i})$? Moreover, in the proof, isn't it enough to have that $A$ and $B$ are independent of $W_i$?

Comment: The random variable $A$ is generated only from $U$, which is independent of $(X,Y,\{W_i\})$, using the distribution function $F_X(x)$, which is just a function. You can imagine you know  $F_X(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ before the outcome $\omega$ and value $X(\omega)$ is determined. For example, in a fair coin flip, you know the mass function is $P[Heads]=P[Tails]=1/2$, but the vector $(1/2,1/2)$ is independent of the outcome of the flip (since constants are independent of everything).

Comment: Yes, the proof only requires that $A$ and $B$ are independent of $\{W_i\}$. But they are indeed also independent of $X, Y$.